# Why do I see edges in the call graph that don't exist using gperftools?

Tags: c++, call-graph, gperftools

Given the following code that either calls f or g

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int f() {
    return 0;
}

int g() {
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    long sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000*1000*1000; i++) {
        int result;
        if(rand() % 2 == 0) {
            result = f();
        }
        else {
            result = g();
        }

        sum += result;
    }
    printf("%ld\n", sum);
}
```

I compile with

```
g++ test.c -o doom -lprofiler -lunwind
```

And run with

```
CPUPROFILE=./test.txt ./test
```

And then generate a gif with

```
pprof --gif ./test ./test.txt > output.gif
```

I get the following [image]

However, I have edges going from f to g, and f to itself, and g to itself. There are no optimizations on (and I tried again with -O0 to be sure), and I've also tried with and without -lunwind.

Why does the profiler think that f calls g (and itself somtimes)? How do I use the profiler correctly?

Comment: [Known problem](https://plus.google.com/app/basic/stream/z12ndrsq3pfjdvjqu04cgdty3lakg3zqdxk0k) (no answer there)

Comment: f<->g edges do no longer show up in the current version (using git HEAD)

Comment: Yes, latest released version does not have this problem anymore.