# Getting call hierarchy in gperftools for an R package

Tags: r, rcpp, call-hierarchy, gperftools

I can use gperftools to produce a call graph, as in for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24668450/why-do-i-see-edges-in-the-call-graph-that-dont-exist-using-gperftools#).

Now I would like to get a call graph for `bind_rows()` in the `dplyr` R package in order to track down [this bug](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1396).

I compiled both `R` and `dplyr` using `CPP/CXXFLAGS=-g -fvar-tracking-assignments` and `LDFLAGS=-lprofiler -lunwind`.

When I run the following:

```
CPUPROFILE="samples.log" R --vanilla <<< "library(dplyr)
ll = lapply(1:1e5, function(x) as.list(setNames(runif(5), letters[1:5])))
print(system.time(bind_rows(ll)))"

pprof --gif /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R samples.log > out.gif
```

All I get is:

[image]

How can I get the call hierarchy so I know which call in [`dplyr`'s bind rows file](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/68254555044e88d4c338e81871c5ca41f2c05053/src/bind.cpp) is the bottleneck?

**edit:** It seems that the `--focus` option is what I need here. But how to connect this to `RecursiveRelease`?

```
pprof --focus=rbind__impl --gif /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R samples.log > out.gif
```

[image]

***edit:*** After recompiling Rcpp with `-g` and linking with `-lprofiler`, I could get the following: [flame.svg](http://imgh.us/flame_2.svg), where 8% gets a good stack trace but most of it still doesn't. Could this be because some library is loaded without `-lprofiler` support?

Comment: Sigh... Can you try [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771)? There's a video of it [*here*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPg3sRpdW1U). And call-graphs are a very [*porous net*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25870103/23771).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I looked at your linked answer before, but didn't quite understand how this relates to my problem (after reading it a bit more carefully I do).
But surely there must be a way to automate call stack sampling using gprof/a profiler and have a graphical representation of the result? (even if it's not named "call graph", I'm not that familiar with the terminology)

Comment: First - you are doing this in order to find speedups, right? If not, ignore me. If so, understand that graphical representations only work for particular subsets of problems - not good enough. Personally examining textual stack samples finds all problems. This is not powerpoint material, it is speedup material. Another point: automating sampling 1) takes too many samples for you to examine ([*you need very few*](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262)), and 2) prevents you from taking them at the time you want, diluting the results.

Comment: I am just watching a video about [flame graphs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=53&v=nZfNehCzGdw) - can you give an example of a problem that one would see with stack samples that this misses?

Comment: Sure: [*look here*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27867426/23771).

Comment: I don't know anything about R. But is it possible that R dlopens and then dlclose-s this dplyr thing? If so it might explain why profile is broken.

Comment: I don't think so. `dplyr` uses `Rcpp`, which when I recompiled I could get a partial good stack trace (see linked flame.svg). I assume this wouldn't happen if there was the issue you described? Could it be that it just loads other libraries that I haven't recompiled with `-lprofiler` so I don't get the proper trace?